# Select every nth element in list, with n rational/non-integer

Tags: python, logic

```
int_list = list(range(1000))  # list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 999]
```

Now I want to select every nth element from this list.
Assume n to be rational. Here: n = 7/3 = 2.333...

The size of the new list should therefore be around 42,85% (1/n) of the original one.
But I don't want the elements to be selected randomly. The gap between the selected elements should be similar, but doesn't need to be always exactly the same.

The result may differ by your algorithm used and the algorithm is up to you as long as it fulfils the requirements. But to answer the comment, here is an example of what the result could look like:

```
int_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
out_list = [0, 2, 4, 8, 10]
```

The size of `out_list` is 45.4545...% of the `int_list`, which isn't 42,85%, but it's the nearest it could get.

Comment: What's the expected result for that example?

Comment: How can you have a non-integer gap between integers?

Comment: I included an example, @superb rain

Comment: The 6 is missing, so it's not every second element.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Probably harder to produce than more similar gaps. Still... why make another example instead of just answering the perfectly fine first one?

Comment: I didn't want to answer the first one because a list with 1000 integers would have taken too much time. I had to remove the elements manually, since I didn't know a proper approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scaling the range by the denominator, stepping with the numerator, and scaling back down by dividing by the denominator:

```
>>> [i // 3 for i in range(0, 3 * 1000, 7)]
[0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 11, 14, 16, 18, 21, 23, 25, 28, 30, 32, 35, ..., 991, 994, 996, 998]
```

Your example is a range, not a list. If you really do have a list, then simply use my numbers as indices, i.e., instead of `i // 3` do `a[i // 3]`.

Answer (score 1):

A rather generic approach where the list doesn't have to consist of the int range and where the rational value could even be less than one:

```
N = 7
D = 3

k = 0
result = []
for i in int_list:
    k += D
    while k >= N:
        result.append(i)
        k -= N
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive take would be

```py
from math import floor

def every_n(lst: list, n: int) -> list:
    l = [] 
    i = 0 
    while i < len(lst): 
        l.append(lst[floor(i)]) 
        i += n 
    return l
```

```py
>>> every_n(range(1000), 7/3)
[0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 11, 14, 16, 18, 21, 23, 25, 28, 30, 32, 35, ..., 991, 994, 996, 998]
```